# Send and get error codes on mysqli_multiquery for each query on PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know if I'm setting something wrong, but I'm using two functions to query two separate databases, each function receives an array of strings with query format I iterate and send them, but if a determined query fails I can't get the exact response of which one failed, what I'm doing wrong here?

```
function ConexionExterna($querylist){
    //Parámetros conexión externa local en desarrollo
    $server_ext = 'localhost';
    $db_user_ext = 'shop-man-dba';
    $db_pass_ext = 'Ursa34[{';
    $db_ext = 'jgd_egamer';
    $querystack = '';
    $conexionexterna = mysqli_connect($server_ext, $db_user_ext, $db_pass_ext, $db_ext) or die ($respuesta = "Error al conectar con base de datos remota");
    foreach ($querylist as $query){
        $querystack += trim($query) . ";";//Separa con ; las sentencias
    }
    $execute_query = mysqli_multi_query($conexionexterna, $querystack);
    if (!$execute_query){
        $respuesta = "Fallo query por " . mysqli_error($conexionexterna);
    }
    else{
        $respuesta = mysqli_fetch_array($execute_query);
    }
    mysqli_close($conexionexterna);//Para permitir alternar entre bases
    return $respuesta;
}
```

My other function it's exactly like this, but it only changes connection parameters

Comment: Why do you need to use `multi_query`? Just perform each query in a loop.

Comment: See the example at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php. You need to use `mysqli_more_results()` to check whether there's another query, and and `mysqli_next_result()` to go to the next set of results.

Comment: @Barmar My purpose was to make the less operations as possible because it will query to an external DB so maybe querying to many times will result in a slower response

Comment: @Barmar I'm reading docs, but I'm still kind of  confused, how could I know which query I sent was the one that caused the error? Let's say  from a set of five the first two failed and the other three were succesful

Comment: Unless the queries are very simple, the bottleneck is unlikely to be in starting the queries.

Comment: Each time you call `mysqli_next_result()` you're working on the results of the next query that you sent. So if you get an error after calling it twice, the error is in the third query.

Comment: Implementing it right now :) how can I mark you as the correct answer? or first I need to post corrected code?

Comment: I didn't post an answer, so you can't mark it as correct.

Comment: You can post your own answer showing how you corrected the code.